# Wrapping javascript with another script

Tags: javascript

I would like to wrap a javascript function with another line that will determine of the script should run or not. The point is to disable the main script if the user is on mobile.

What I can't work out is how to get this to work.

This is the initial script

```
    <script>


    function init() {

        window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
            var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                shrinkOn = 200,
                header = document.querySelector("header");
            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                classie.add(header,"smaller");
            } else {
                if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                    classie.remove(header,"smaller");
                }
            }

        });

            } 
    window.onload = init();

</script>
```

This is the script that I want to wrap it with.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if(window.innerWidth > 568){
        ...execute script
    }
});
```

How would I go about to structure the code to make this happen?

Thanks,
Tobias

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want to do.  Do you want to run the scroll event handler when resize goes below 568?  Show us the desired code, even if it does not work. That will help us understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I want it to run when it's over 568. So when the page loads on smaller screen the scroll event handler doesn't run at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you right it should suffice to add

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 568) return;
```

to the start of your `init` function or the event handler.

Comment: This works just fine, but only on load. I'm looking for something that would react to a resizing of the window as well.

Comment: This actually seem to work. Even when resizing, didn't expect that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/).

```
function init() {
  //your code …
}

enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 568px)", {
   match : init,  //always executing when media query is matched OR:
   setup : init,  //only triggered the first time the media query is matched, in combination with:
   deferSetup : true
});
```

Comment: I've looked in to this, but I'm just not skilled enough to figure it out. Is your code all I need or would I need other resources as well?

Comment: You'll have to download and load the [enquire.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WickyNilliams/enquire.js/master/dist/enquire.min.js) as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look in to this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using media queries?
Here are few links:


[Conditionally load JavaScript based on media query](http://responsivedesign.is/develop/javascript/conditionally-load-javascript-based-on-media-query)

[Conditional loading of resources with mediaqueries](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/)

Hope this helps you out in finding a solution.